# Server admin panel

Tags: python, ide, server, admin-console

Now I use PythonAnyWhere service for my website hosting. It is quite useful, provides ability to edit and run any code directly in browser. However, it lacks possibility to use WebSockets. Therefore, I would like to use VPS, it's cheaper and allows to use any technologies. But I also want to have an analogue of PythonAnyWhere admin console, some sort of online IDE, to abstract from bash, FTP and desktop IDE, and work with code and other files straight in a browser. Are there any tools, solutions for that?

**Update:**

I would like to have these features:

- Upload, rename and move files on my server
- See size of files and directories
- Edit text files (and HTML, CSS, JS, Python code)
- Online bash console

It will be used on Linux-based Xen or OpenVZ server OS. If possible, I would like to have free solution. If needed, I can write some features myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is a beginner as was I, and is interested in what I've chosen `:)` I found no single, comprehensive tool, but lots of

- [**FileZilla**](https://filezilla-project.org) (one any other similar software) to up-/download the files, move or rename them through [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol). And [**git**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) for simple managing of large projects. Also, [**rsync**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) may be helpful.
  For really big projects running on multiple machines, Docker+Kubernetes virtualisation tools may be used.
- Text & code files I mostly manage on my own computer with favourites apps, and then upload the files with the mentioned tools. But I also get mastered (to some extent) [**vim**](https://www.vim.org) which is quite handy for quick files view or editing.
- SSH (with pretty [**tmux**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux), [**mosh**](https://mosh.org)), and lots of useful bash commands for all the other needs. To automate tasks, it's possible to write large scripts, or even use powerful tools like [**ansible**](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html).
- It's also important to monitor server state. To accomplish this, the [**netdata**](https://github.com/netdata/netdata) tool may be used.